# Cannot receive media attachment file in Twilio Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-flex

Project description:
Currently we have our customers using various chat platforms such as whatsapp , and slack where our contact center is forced to use the same. However, we would like to give Twilio flex platform to our contact service team so that they can reply messages coming from whatsapp, slack.

Query regarding media messages:
I use Javascript Client SDK for front end and connect Twilio Flex as an agent. Chat is working fine. I can send / Receive messages. But, when I send media files through SDK, '*Media messages are not supported'* is displaying in Twilio Flex. When I use get All Messages from API able to get that media file as message with `type = media`. Also media SID is created for the uploaded file. But not able to view the same file in twilio flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, Flex does not support media attachments. You could possibly work on some logic to pass in the media URL to the agent via chat, but I have not seen any code examples to share.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old OLD question, but there's a bit better answer now.

https://github.com/jprix/mms2FlexChat/tree/master/function

Twilio Flex Plugin SAMPLE that shows media use with Flex and WhatsApp.  Caveat:  even the sample is somewhat old at this point, but should at least be educational.

HTH